# Why is Edward Deegan hostile?

Tags: fallout-4

And who is he anyway?

I just entered Bunker Hill, minding my own business, and the guy starts shooting at me. I've never met him and I have no quest involving him, most importantly I CAN'T KILL HIM. Whenever I deplete his HP, he goes down for a few seconds before getting back up and starts shooting me again.

I can't do anything in Bunker Hill because all the NPCs keep running away from me, yelling "It's not my fight".

It's not mine either!

Comment: [Edward Deegan](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Edward_Deegan) works for [Jack Cabot](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_Cabot). Did you do any of their quests? If you fought the robots outside [Cabot House](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Cabot_House), that might make him hostile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3st72o/any_way_of_setting_a_unkillable_hostile_npc_to/) about the same issue here.

Apparently, as stated in a comment, I killed some robots around Cabot House just prior to entering Bunker Hill, which made Mr Deegan hostile towards me (even if the robots attacked me first... I didn't even enter the place either, they probably just got caught in a crossfire between some raiders and I)

I ended up waiting two full in-game days (as was suggested in the link provided) and Edward Deegan is no longer hostile.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - I actually went to Cabot House to start the quest, but there were raiders (Rust Devils actually) and while I was fighting them - the Cabot robots were fighting them too - and I must've hit one of the Cabot robots with my plasma flamer or something, because then they were hostile and I had to kill them. Then I went inside (the speaker let me in, of course) and Edward Deegan and Jack Cabot tried to kill me.

I ended up turning the combat AI off ("tcai" on console) so they just froze and I left and ran far away so they wouldn't chase me when I turned the AI back on. (If you don't do the console stuff you could probably just run away until they leave you alone).

I did go and do another quest or two (not sure how many days went by) and I went back and they weren't hostile and the quest continued as normal.

On to my Charisma bobblehead!

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! We generally expect each new answer to be a completely new answer. This seems like you're simply confirming the accepted answer, rather than providing anything new. A comment probably would have sufficed, if not simply an upvote. I guess the note about the console command provides an alternative or augmented solution.